# Problem in viewing attachment (image) of API BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge

Looking at some tutorials (I can't find the link I consulted), I was able to access an issue's attachment, but I'm not able to transform the data (Binary) into an image. follows an image of how my response is coming.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvlcI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps referring to https://bim360-issue-editor.herokuapp.com? The source code of this sample is available at https://github.com/petrbroz/bim360-issue-editor.

Here's how the server side requests the attachment: https://github.com/petrbroz/bim360-issue-editor/blob/develop/routes/api/issues.js#L309-L331.

And here's how the client side turns it into an image:
https://github.com/petrbroz/bim360-issue-editor/blob/develop/public/issues.js#L405-L443